# Windows 10 totally broken, possibly after November 12th update

Tags: windows-10

Today I turned on my Computer which ran fine for a year and I have (at least) the following issues:

- Windows Explorer does not open
- Windows Settings do not open
- Cortana does not search
- One-Drive does not work

Basically I all I can do is browse the web.

Last working version was Windows 10 1903.

1. Is anybody having similar issues?
2. How can I check, which windows version I have without using Settings-System?
3. How can I start update rollback dialog without using Settings?

---

Update: While following John's suggestion the Explorer suddenly opened (about 30 Minutes after the system started). I could use settings, but it would not open Update history (got stuck on the button animation).

I researched the command prompt update history: wmic qfe list, which showed me no apparent changes to the system.

I then started the "update search" which failed 3 times, but on the 4th try I could update to 1909 and now the problem seems to be fixed.

Comment: It sounds like your system was preparing to install Windows 10 version 1909, and your odd system state, was due to that fact.  When you performed the reboot at the appropriate time, the update was installed, the behavior shouldn't have happened but feature updates since 1709+ are partially installed in the background

Comment: Not likely. I rebootet twice without any effect and the update files startet downloading only after manual invoked.

Comment: I admit my theory assumes the feature update was being downloaded without you "seeking" it, and you having to search for the update, is suppose to be how 1909 gets installed.  However, I have seen strange things happen, while the feature update was being prepared to be installed in the background in the past.

Answer (score 1):

When you have this many issues (something was happening before the update) as Windows 10 V1909 seems fine on any mine or client machines, run a Windows 10 Repair Install and Keep Everything to correct this

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button, select Save.
Create a USB Windows Installation key and then run Setup on the USB Key. 
This will launch the Repair and proceed normally

Comment: Always back up your files and your application installers/registration keys before doing this.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage A repair install doesn't touch user files, it just replaces the system files, mainly those in `%WinDir%`, but also a minute amount found in `%ProgramFiles%`, `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`, and `%ProgramData%`.  To see which files are replaced in the latter three, open the `install.wim`/`install.esd` from the install ISO in 7zip _(more efficient that mounting the WIM)_.  The system-wide registry hives can be found in `%WinDir%\System32\config` (~12 in total)

Answer (score 0):

Please perform the following:

1. ```powershell
   DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
   ```

   - *Internet connection required*

     - If this fails, issue the below, then re-run #1

       ```powershell
       DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup
       ```
   - Reboot once completed
2. ```powershell
   SFC /ScanNow
   ```

   - Reboot once completed

If the above doesn't work, a Repair Install will need to be performed, as detailed in [@John's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1502058/529800)

Comment: @John - Please do not ask users to accept your answer.  You can remind them it's possible to accept answers, but comments asking them to specifically accept your answer, is frowned upon.  *I would make this comment to any users that requested their answer be accepted in a comment*